# Show hide div with active state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i amend this code please so that the buttons change on the active. It's getting soemwhere with toggleClass but the button that was formerly active remains active.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
           jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    });
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).toggleClass( "greenactive"      
   ).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

my button code

```
<ul class="choose">
<li><a class="showSingle" target="1">Email Order</a></li>
<li><a class="showSingle" target="2">Order and Pay Now</a></li>
</ul>
```

the divs

```
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
content
</div>

<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
content
</div>
```

style

```
a.greenactive {background:green}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `removeClass()` before `addclass()`

```js
$('.showSingle').click(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('.showSingle').removeClass('greenactive');
    $(this).addClass("greenactive")
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

```css
a.greenactive {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="choose">
    <li>
        <a class="showSingle" target="1">Email Order</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="showSingle" target="2">Order and Pay Now</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">content1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">content2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `removeClass()` on all the `.showSingle` elements before toggling the class on the one which raised the event:

```
$('.showSingle').removeClass('greenactive');
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/78dtypuw/)